# Выделить ячейку выпадающего списка другим цветом

Tags: excel

Допустим, что у меня есть 3 значения в выпадающем списке. Мне нужно, чтобы второе значение списка было отмечено красным цветом, а остальные остались прежние. Как мне это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По-моему, никак. Цвета выпадающего списка всегда белые.

Comment: Я отчетливо помню, как меняла сам текст одной позиции на красный, но остальные были неформатированные. Если есть какой-то способ, даже на VBA такое сделать, дайте знать, пожалуйста.

Comment: Это вы, наверное, меняли цвета в ячейке с помощью правила условного форматирования, а не в выпадающем списке. Чтобы поменять цвета в выпадающем списке, нужно написать свой ActiveX компонент.

Comment: Да, только это занятие не для новичков. Для этого нужно очень хорошо знать язык и установить кучу библиотек.